# Angular2 - variable doesn't get updated

Tags: html, angular, variables, types, angular2-directives

I have a function getCallList() to retrieve call list history. listEmpty is a variable initially set to false indicating call list is not null. As getCallList is called, I think template is rendered before listEmpty variable gets updated.

```
public getcallList() {
    let api = ApiBuilder.getInstance();
    this.callDataUrl = api.getcallReportRulesGenericURL();
    let that = this;
    return this.http
      .get(this.callDataUrl, {})
      .map(response => {
        let callDataList = new Array<callRealsData>();
        let res = response.json();
        let reponseStatus = response.status;
        if (reponseStatus === this.RET_SUCCESS) {
          let reportRules = res.data.report_rules;
          if (reportRules.length == 0) {
            that.listEmpty = true;
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < reportRules.length; i++) {
            let callData = new callRealsData();
            callData.id = reportRules[i].id;
            callData.name = reportRules[i].name;
            callData.startTime = reportRules[i].start_time;
            callData.endTime = reportRules[i].end_time;
            callData.type = reportRules[i].type;
            callDataList.push(callData);
          }
        } else {
          console.log(this.className + ': API response failed');
        }
        return callDataList;
      });
  }
```

Initially listEmpty variable is assigned false.
On the HTML part, there is *ngIf conditionally adding a body to the code.

```
<div *ngIf="callList.listEmpty">
        <p class="noItem">Call list empty</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!callList.listEmpty" class="content">
            <div class="spinner">
                <mdl-spinner *ngIf="!dataLoaded" class="progress contentZIndex" [active]="true"></mdl-spinner>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let item of callService.storesHavingCallList">
                <div>
                    <data-store [store]="item"></data-store>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When listEmpty is expected to be true, spinner gets displayed for few seconds and then vanishes.As soon as it vanishes "Call list empty" message is shown.Is it possible to remove the spinner appearing before variable getting updated.Can any one give me some insight on the same.

Comment: how callList.listEmpty value is set and where?

Comment: I have updated my question.Can you go through the same?

Comment: As per your code, the scenario is working properly. The value of listEmpty is set in the response of the API so it will take time to update the variable, hence the spinner and then the empty message. Try adding condition to spinner div with another variable. That might work